# Junk values in first two elements of resizable array class with parenthesis operator overload

Tags: c++, arrays, overloading, operator-keyword, parentheses

I am working on a project for school where we are creating an ExpandArray class that will dynamically allocate an array and as values are added or removed it will expand or contract based on a percentage.

The issue I am having is with the parenthesis operator overload function.  I have a version that works correctly.  In my main, I create an object named ea of type ExpandArray and send it an array of values 1 thru 10.  I then cout << ea(3,7);  which should print out 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.

This works in one version that I have compiled that I was using for testing, but in every other version, even when I create a new project from scratch and copy and paste the text from the working version, I get junkvalue, junkvalue, 6, 7, 8.

I even checked the filepath for the header file to ensure the test version wasn't somehow accidentally building based on files in another location.

The following is the relevant code I have:

```
template<class OT>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const ExpandArray<OT>& ea)
{
    if(ea._size == 0)
        os << "This array is empty";
    else
    {
        os << ea._array[0];
        for(unsigned i = 1; i < ea._size;++i)
            os << ", " << ea._array[i];
    }
    return os;
}

template<class T>
ExpandArray<T> ExpandArray<T>::operator()(int first, int last)const
{
    int Afirst = first - _Vindex;
    int Alast = last - _Vindex;
    if(Afirst < 0 || Afirst > _size - 1 || Alast < 0 || Alast > _size - 1)
    {
        cout << "Error: ExpandArray<T>::operator()(int first, int last)const" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return *this;
    }
    ExpandArray<T> temp(_Vindex, _perc);
    for(unsigned i = Afirst;i <= Alast;++i)
    {
        temp.append(_array[i]);
    }
    return temp;
}

template<class T>
void ExpandArray<T>::append(const T& t)
{
    if(_size >= _alloc)
    {
        if(_alloc < MIN_ALLOC)
        {
            _alloc = MIN_ALLOC;
            _array = new T[_alloc];
        }
        else if(_size <= (_alloc / (_perc + 1)))
        {
            _alloc /= (_perc + 1);
            T* temp;
            temp = new T[_alloc];
            for(unsigned i = 0;i < _size; ++i)
                temp[i] = _array[i];
            _array = temp;
            delete &temp;
        }
        else
        {
            _alloc *= (_perc + 1);
            T* temp;
            temp = new T[_alloc];
            for(unsigned i = 0;i < _size; ++i)
                temp[i] = _array[i];
            _array = temp;
            delete &temp;
        }
    }
    _array[_size++] = t;
}
```

And my main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ExpandArray.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
    ExpandArray<int> ea(arr, 10);
    cout << ea(3,7) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If I print out _array[3] as the last line of the parenthesis operator overload function, it prints out the correct value of 4.  If i print out the same _array[3] as the first line in the insertion operator overload function, I get the junk value.  The first two elements printing out are a different random huge number each time I build and run it.  For reference, running it now displays 6035096, 6033256, 6, 7, 8

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: `delete &temp;` is wrong, there is no need to take address here, there is no need to delete new items leaking old items leaving you with a dangling pointer. All those things lead to undefined behavior. It should be `std::swap(_array, temp); delete [] temp;`

Comment: Thank you, this, however, is still printing junk values for the first two elements.

Comment: Do you have a copy constructor?

Comment: Yes, it just makes all the members = to ea.member

Comment: Well there's your problem. The `ExpandArray` you're returning is a copy of `temp`, so it'll just copy the `_array` pointer of `temp`. But then `temp` goes out of scope and deallocates that memory! You're left with undefined behavior. You need to create a **deep copy** instead of a shallow one. Create and allocate a new `_array` in the copy constructor.

Comment: Have you tried using `valgrind` or clang/gcc's address sanitizer?  Junk values makes me think lifetime issue, and either of those tools would help.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I have NO clue why this is working in the one version I have without this method, but it is now also working in this version.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you scohe001!!!

My copy constructor was as follows:

```
template<class T>
ExpandArray<T>::ExpandArray(const ExpandArray& ea)
{
    _array = ea._array;
    _size = ea._size;
    _alloc = ea._alloc;
    _Vindex = ea._Vindex;
    _perc = ea._perc;
}
```

I changed it to:

```
template<class T>
ExpandArray<T>::ExpandArray(const ExpandArray& ea)
{
    _array = new T[ea._size];
    for(unsigned i = 0;i < ea._size;++i)
    {
        _array[i] = ea._array[i];
    }
    _size = ea._size;
    _alloc = ea._alloc;
    _Vindex = ea._Vindex;
    _perc = ea._perc;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help! A few quick tips though: I'm not sure what all of your members do, but if `_alloc` is how much space is allocated, you shouldn't be doing `_alloc = ea._alloc` because you've allocated `ea._size` space, right? For the copy constructor I'd suggest setting up the members like the default constructor (set all to 0 probably) and then looping through `ea` and calling `append`. Better to use what you've already created, you'll cause less bugs!